# How can I generate extended Custom Notification like below image?

Tags: android, notifications

Adding View into the Remoteviews of Notification custome xml not working properly.

I want the Extended Notification with two Action Buttons and stack managed in that.

[image]

Comment: Did you read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout

Comment: Read official docs [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Ya I read the above document and already implement it all three style.