# Android custom notification layout with RemoteViews

Tags: android, xml, layout, notifications

I'm trying to create a custom notification for my android app using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout), and I stumbled upon a problem which I tried to resolve for the last 2 hours.

Only the imageview of my layout shows, and I can't figure out how to make it works like intended.

My code:

```
package be.ac.ucl.lfsab1509.cumulus.services;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import be.ac.ucl.lfsab1509.cumulus.R;
import be.ac.ucl.lfsab1509.cumulus.activities.MainActivity;
import be.ac.ucl.lfsab1509.cumulus.entities.Song;

public class CumulusNotification {

private CumulusService mCtx;
private CumulusMediaPlayer mPlayer;
private Notification mNotification;
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
private RemoteViews mContentView;

public CumulusNotification(CumulusService ctx, CumulusMediaPlayer player){
    mCtx = ctx;
    mPlayer = player;

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mCtx);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_cumulus_notification);
    //mBuilder.setContentTitle("Cumulus is playing");
    //mBuilder.setTicker("Cumulus");
    //mBuilder.setContentText(mCtx.getCurrentSong().title());

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mCtx);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mContentView = new RemoteViews(mCtx.getPackageName(), R.layout.statusbar);
    mContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.notifimage, R.drawable.cumulus_icon);
    mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notiftitle, "Custom notification");
    mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.notiftext, "This is a custom layout");
    mBuilder.setContent(mContentView);
}

public void startNotification() {
    mNotification = mBuilder.build();
    //mNotification.contentView = mContentView;
    mCtx.startForeground(R.integer.NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}

public void updateSong(Song song){
    mBuilder.setContentText(song.title());
    mNotification = mBuilder.build();
    mCtx.startForeground(R.integer.NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
}
}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:gravity="left" >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/notifimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/notiftitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notifimage" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/notiftext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notifimage"
    android:layout_below="@id/notiftitle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: my notification]

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you post the statusbar.xml that'd make helping you fix the layout a lot easier...

Comment: Done! Like I said, like in the original post

Comment: @HappyRave -  were you able to solve it ? I am facing same issue. Thx

Comment: Why do you have `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/notifimage"` on both TextViews?

Answer (score 13):

Problem is you have not set the correct contentView.

```
mBuilder.setContent(contentView);
```

But your remote view is mContentView. change it to

```
mBuilder.setContent(mContentView);
```

Here is a sample

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.test_tt);
    mContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
    mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
    mBuilder.setContent(mContentView);

    startForeground(1001, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: That's not it, it was just a typo here on stack overflow!
If this was in my actual code it would not even compile ^^

Comment: Also, remove the style from layout what you have set for TextView. it should be a valid Style if required

Answer (score 2):

You can see working example here:
http://www.laurivan.com/android-notifications-with-custom-layout/

I think, adding

```
// Set Icon
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallimage)
// Set Ticker Message
.setTicker("Noification is created");
```

to your builder can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a layout issue, the more that I think about it. I think that if you were to set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the `TextView`s, you'd get what you were looking for. It looks like it's laying them out to the right of the `ImageView`, but not giving them any width at layout time, since they don't ask for any, and they don't have any content.

If that doesn't work, let us know!

Comment: Now the whole java file is available :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-callbacks-remoteviews-and-notifications) post explains very cool.

Basically and so:

```
RemoteViews downloadViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.download_notification);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                .setContentText("Content Text")
                .setContent(downloadViews)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
        final Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.bigContentView = downloadViews;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```