# Can't find information on how to add to this element, Android

Tags: android

[SOLVED = I can't add to it, it's based on the active ROM]

Sorry for the vague questioning, I wasn't sure quite how to create it.

I'm wanting to add toggle buttons, or at least other elements into this part of android;

[image: Screen element]

I can't find any documents on how to add to this element of Android, and I'm wondering if we actually can? Does anyone know what this element is even called and can link me to the appropriate android doc?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that is part of the ROM, are you looking to create an custom ROM or add to it with your own app?

Comment: Looking to add to it with my own app, for arguments sake lets say something as easy as adding an orientation lock toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application that ships with Android, hence you cannot change its behavior. It has a predefined set of elements that can be present on it. If you want to create a custom version of it, you will need to create a custom ROM.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to the quick settings screen on my Samsung and it created by the phone manufacturer. You could create a custom ROM, but I don't think this is what you really want.

The closest I think you can get is the notification bar, which can use a custom layout:

[Change Notification Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout)

Also Take a look at the WatchOn app, which has a relatively complex control embedded into the notification screen:

[image: http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2013/07/Samsung_Galaxy_S_4_Remote_Control_Notification_Panel.jpg]