# How to add buttons inside android notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have managed to create this kind of notifications

[image]

following this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html#big-view

However I cannot find any documentation on how to achieve this style:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add custom notification layout and through the remote views.

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18414768/713778

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Custom notification layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification), you can set a custom content of the notification with [`Notification.Builder.setContent(RemoteViews)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContent%28android.widget.RemoteViews%29)