# Android Listview in notification

Tags: android, listview, notifications, remoteview

Can I have a listview in a notification in Android 3.0+? And if so, maybe a scrollable list?

I have seen that this can be done in a widget, but can't seem to find the way to do it for a notification. So far I have a notification with a custom layout using RemoteViews. Everything working ok, just wondering if I can use a list in the custom layout somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: chech this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18414768/3326331)

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I already have that working. I have a custom layout with some text and buttons. Now I need a list in there, with an ArrayAdapter, and that is not the way to do it. Or at least I don't see it...How do you inflate a listview using RemoteViews that way?

Comment: @fcristel hey have you found any solution for it ?

Comment: No I didn't. If someone knows how to get this going, please post it here. Thanks