# Android:Modify Pending Notification's Content

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to modify existing notifications in android.

**What I have in my app**
When a notification is already in system tray and another notification appears, the second one overwrites the first notification content.

**What I am looking for**

If second Notification arrives then instead of overwriting the first I need to change title to show `2 New Messages` and go on incrementing as notifications arrive.

[image: What it should look like]

**Code Implemented**

```
      Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                R.drawable.icon);
        Intent launchActivity = new Intent(ctx, CordovaApp.class);

        launchActivity.putExtra("heading",newsHeader);
        launchActivity.putExtra("content",newsText);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx,0, launchActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(launchActivity);
        if(pi==null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Pending Intenet is null.");
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Pending Intenet is not null.");
        }

        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setContentTitle(newsHeader)
        .setContentText(newsText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setLargeIcon(icon)
        .setContentIntent(pi)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .build();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(0, noti);
```

**Update**

I implemented the solution mentioned below by @yogendra and now I am getting two separate notifications. Instead of getting stacked. Below is updated code

```
Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
            .setContentTitle(newsHeader)
            .setContentText(newsText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setLights(Color.parseColor("green"), 5000, 5000)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(2)
            .setTicker("Notification from App")
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .build();
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            int timeSeconds = (int)System.currentTimeMillis()%Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            Log.i(TAG,"Timing function called "+timeSeconds);
            nm.notify(timeSeconds, noti);
```

Comment: you should change the `ID` for that  `nm.notify(count++, noti);`

Comment: Thanks @MD..can you please post some relevant code. Also, how do I know if notification is already present. So, that I can print the custom message instead of Actual title.

Comment: See the Mr. Smith answer's and i will give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

See your code

```
 nm.notify(0, noti);
```

where

```
notify(int id, Notification notification)
```

Here `0` is the **ID of notification** which is to be managed with respect to each notification. If you want to show a different notification your notification id should be unique each time. If you try to post a notification with the same notification id your previously displayed notification will be replaced with the latest notification.

**Solution**

Now you need to display a custom notification with a custom layout and update the counter each time .

Source code to create a [Custom Notification.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout)

Answer (score 0):

create global  variable in your class :

```
private int count = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> notificationList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "email";
```

/*call method createNotification when you need to create notification and pass message what you need to show on message.*/

```
private void createNotification(String notificationMassage) {


    notificationList.add(notificationMassage);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // Create builder
    Builder summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(notificationList.size()+" new messages")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.settings)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true);




    // Create style 
    InboxStyle nStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    nStyle.setBigContentTitle(notificationList.size()+" new messages");
    nStyle.setSummaryText("Summery Text...<you can set as blank>");

    for (String Str : notificationList) {
        nStyle.addLine(Str);
    }
    summaryNotification.setStyle(nStyle);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, summaryNotification.build());
    count++;
}
```

/**
please clear notification array list after tap on notification.
*/

For more detail please refer below link:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html#AddGroup

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html#AddGroup

Comment: thanks @yogendra. I am not getting the `.setGroup` method in my `NotificationCompact`. Is it a specific android support jar to be downloaded.?

Comment: no @inceptor361. Its working at my side. please import proper package name and clean your project.

Comment: I implemented the above solution. now the problem is I am getting two separate notifications. and not stacked.

Comment: please check my answer. I changed.