# Android Notification with BigPicture style and BigText style

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

Does anyone can help me out here.How to implement BigPictureStyle notification with multiline summary text in android.I am able to do by reducing text size which I don't want to.Please help me out on this.

Can we combine two types of notification like big picture and big text style?Does any one know about this?

Comment: Read this have nice example itself in developer.android site http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/notify-user/expanded.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html

Comment: @AjayPandya I know these styles but problem is in BigPicture style you can't add multiline summary text which I want to do and in BigView Style you can't add picture below summary text.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirement i can figured out that you have to create custom layout for notification because basically you can not combine both BigPicture and BitText style so you have to go with the custom view for notification.

you can read this [Custom notification for android](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) as well example from  this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18414768/3514144)