# How to set Text in Notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

How can I set this text line of the notification. my code to simulate what is in the image is 
    `Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Michael")
        .setContentText("Dinner tonight?")
        .setSubText("let's grab some dinner.Are you free?")
        .setLargeIcon(myBitMap)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_archive, "ARCHIVE", null)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_reply, "REPLY", null)
        .build()`

[image]

EDIT

or no way , I've to use custom view ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Notification Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Eugen Pechanec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2444099/eugen-pechanec)

the answer is in that link 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html