# Show text below notification button

Tags: android, android-notifications

[image]

In the above image the I am quite sure that the notification style is `Notification.MessageStyle`
which is working proerly in my code, but I am not able to set the text below it the one which in the image shows the email and another text which is showing the number of unread messages. How do I show the two textviews there?

My Code:

```
         Person user = new Person.Builder().setIcon(IconCompat.createWithBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))).setName("You").build();
                    NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle style = new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle(user)
                            .setConversationTitle("Title")
                            .addMessage("hi", System.currentTimeMillis(), new Person.Builder().setName("Pemba").build())
                            .addMessage("hello", System.currentTimeMillis(), new Person.Builder().setName("Suku").build())
                            .addMessage("hello", System.currentTimeMillis(), new Person.Builder().build())

.setGroupConversation(true);


                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);


                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

                    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNNEL_ID);
                    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.robot_noti)
                            .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))

                            .addAction(android.R.drawable.radiobutton_on_background, "Button", pIntent)
                            .setStyle(style)
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                            .setAutoCancel(true);


                    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setContentText` and `setSubText`
Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359054/how-to-set-text-in-notification) question.

For the number of messages which are unread:
Hope [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html) helps

Comment: thanks the subtext shows the email text but what about the text on the bottom right?

Comment: Use `setNumber(number here);` Here is the link to an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602072/styling-notification-inboxstyle