# Android - Notification Bar with No Small Icon

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have written an app, that has to have push notifications. As you know, notifications have a large icon and a small icon. The large icon is showed when you pull down the notification bar, and the small icon is showed when the notification bar is up on top of the screen. My problem is, I do not want to have a small icon so that the user only sees my notification when they pull down the notification bar. There are a couple of answers to this question on StackOverFlow, but they all suggest making the small icon the transparent color. Yes, when you make it transparent, it seems to be no longer visible in the notification bar, but it's actually still there. Let's say another app on the device pushes a notification, and then your app pushes its notification. In this case, your icon is "invisible" but because their notification was pushed first, their notification doesn't show up in the most left up corner of the screen. This is because your small icon is there, it is just transparent. Here is my code that pushes the notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(show))
                    .setContentTitle(show)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setContentText(timeUpdater.getCurrentDate());

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(101, mBuilder.build());
```

EDIT: I am currently using a small icon since I could not find a solution.

Comment: This post at SO briefly expalins how to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will Help you.

> For nice-to-know background information that isn't aimed specifically
>   at the user. For example, weather or nearby places of interest.

```
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
```