# How to create notification with margin

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am trying to get a notification to have the margin like this notification below:

[image]

You see how the white of the notification doesn't touch the edge of the screen... that's what I mean.

I tried this:

```
BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigStyle.bigText(eventDescription);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.notif_background))
        .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
        .setContentText(eventLocation)
        .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map,
                getString(R.string.map), mapPendingIntent)
        .setStyle(bigStyle);
```

But that produces the card touching the edge of the screen. How can I achieve this?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout

Answer (score 0):

On Android Wear, the position and size of the notifications is controlled by the system. The screenshot you've posted is from an older version of Android Wear - the new styling always has cards touching the edge of the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response that is what I was fearing. Would you happen to have a reference to this information? I would deeply appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think it is specifically called out except for the [note on the top of the training page](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html) about only taking the text and icons from your notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an custom view by using a [RemoteView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html).

// Inflate the notification layout as RemoteViews

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using the old version of android wear try using [InboxStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html), it is the other style beside BigTextStyle.

> To add the extended content to your notification, call [setStyle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setStyle(android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Style)) on the [NotificationCompat.Builder object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html), passing it an instance of
>   either [BigTextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html) or [InboxStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html).

```
InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
```

Hope this helps.