# Use RatingBar in notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-view, ratingbar, remoteview

I am developing an app in which user can give reviews and I am pushing notification to that user to whom review is posted. Now I have a requirement from client to show the rating in the notification

I have searched about it and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout) solution to customize the notification but now I am not getting how to use `RatingBar`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `android.widget.RatingBar` inside notification, because it's not allowed to be used with `RemoteViews` mechanism. The way you determine whether a particular view is a eligible to use in notifications is checking whether that view is annotated with [`@RemoteView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.RemoteView.html).

For example, you can [see](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#303), that `TextView` is annotated with `@RemoteView`. `RatingBar` is **not**.

There are limited amount of views that are allowed to be used with `RemoteViews` mechanism. I couldn't find a list of those view in documentation, but a simple search within Android Studio will reveal all of them.

[image]